# Помогите выровнять форму

Tags: html, css

Как выровнять форму по центру так, чтобы при изменении ширины инпутов ничего не "съезжало". Пытался вручную подогнать ширину формы под размер контента и применить `margin: auto`, но тогда при изменении размера инпута или зума страницы все "едет".

```css
form {
  width: 323px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text"   id="left"/>
  <input type="submit" value=">>"/>
  <input type="text"   id="right"/>
</form>
<canvas width="40" height="200"></canvas>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4epmas8k/

Т.е. пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы submit-btn была над канвой и при изменении ширины инпутов ничего не съезжало.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4epmas8k/ - так? Или я не правильно вас понял?

Comment: Там ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/4epmas8k/3/

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <form>
        <input type="text"   id="left"/>
        <input type="submit" value=">>"/>
        <input type="text"   id="right"/>
    </form>
</div>

.form-wrapper { text-align: center; }
form { display: inline-block; }
```